# Spring Security Users With Same Name

Tags: spring-security

If two users have same username  in the database then how can spring security handle that?
I have two users with following login CREDENTIALS in database:-
1.Username:rohit password:1234
2.Username:rohit password:123

Comment: What is your database schema? Which columns are unique? What's the primary key? Is your database relational at all?

Answer (score 1):

That means the user cannot be unique identified by the username only. So you have to think about the business requirements how to unique identify an user based on the information collected from the user request.

Enforcing the username to be unique across the system can definitely solve the problem. Ask the product owner if it is okay to do it .If not , ask him how to handle such case from the business 's point of view. Then based on the actual requirements of how to unique identify an user , you may need to customise the following classes (Assuming you are using the default username and password login form and authenticate against the user records from DB using JDBC) :

- `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`
- `DaoAuthenticationProvider`
- `UserDetailsService`

Comment: Consider adding a link to a worked example, like https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database